# in mysql database how to find 'X' table exist or not?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 19 MySQL databases, where a number of tables get created every year as per event (there are 19 events going on), but every year there are new competitions that get introduced so new tables get created.  Competitions are not the same in all 19 events. 
We are preparing central system to keep a track of data of all 19 events. Now here is the situation where we have to find out whether a table exist or not; if exist then fire query.

So, in MySQL, how to find if "X" table exist or not?

Comment: "a number of tables get created every year as per event" . . . Ooooh, that doesn't sound good. But that should probably be another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

**show tables** 
in mysql or PHPmyadmin it will list down all the tables

Or

You can find specific table

show tables LIKE '%%'

E.g show tables LIKE '%customer%'

Comment: hi, Thank you very much for your valuable support.

Comment: hi, Thank you very much for your valuable support. Its working in mysql prompt but when i am trying in PHP its not retrieving any answer. can you help me in this issue?

Comment: Now Problem is solved ......thank you very much for your help....{PHP CODE                                                                              $temp = "test";
 $qr = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$temp'";
 $qr_id = mysql_query($qr);
 $qr_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qr_id);
 echo "<br />Id: ".$qr_num_rows;                             }

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'X';
```

And the normal rules for LIKE apply, so this is also valid:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'foo%';
```

Comment: Use this just like you would a select, and see if it returns a row of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable support. Its working in mysql prompt/phpmyadmin but when i am trying in PHP code its not retrieving any answer. can you help me in this issue?

Comment: Now Problem is solved ......thank you very much for your help....
{PHP CODE 
$temp = "test"; 
$qr = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$temp'"; $qr_id = mysql_query($qr); $qr_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qr_id); echo "<br />Id: ".$qr_num_rows; }

Answer (score 0):

execute the query `show tables;` and the list of tables name.

Iterate the table list and find out 'x' exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can Just write :

```
show tables LIKE '%X%'
```

It will solve your problem